# Hide some React component children depending on user role

Tags: reactjs, permissions, redux, roles

I am writing a single page application in React and Redux (with a Node.js backend).

I want to implement role-based access control and want to control the display of certain parts (or sub parts) of the app.

I'm going to get permissions list from Node.js, which is just an object with such structure:

```
{
  users: 'read',
  models: 'write',
  ...
  dictionaries: 'none',
}
```

**key** is protected resource,

**value** is user permission for this resource (one of: `none`, `read`, `write`).

I'm storing it into redux state. Seems easy enough.

`none` permission will be checked by `react-router` routes `onEnter/onChange` hooks or `redux-auth-wrapper`. It seems easy too.

But what is the best way to apply `read/write` permissions to any component view (e.g. hide edit button in Models component if the user has `{ models: 'read' }` permission).

I've found [this solution](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/user-permissions/3752/3) and change it a bit for my task:

```
class Check extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    resource: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    permission: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['read', 'write']),
    userPermissions: React.PropTypes.object,
  };

  // Checks that user permission for resource is the same or greater than required
  allowed() {
    const permissions = ['read', 'write'];
    const { permission, userPermissions } = this.props;
    const userPermission = userPermissions[resource] || 'none';

    return permissions.indexOf(userPermission) >= permissions.indexOf(permission)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.allowed()) return { this.props.children };
  }
}

export default connect(userPermissionsSelector)(Check)
```

where `userPermissionsSelector` would be something like this: `(store) => store.userPermisisons` and returns user permission object.

Then wrap protected element with `Check`:

```
<Check resource="models" permission="write">
  <Button>Edit model</Button>
</Check>
```

so if user doesn't have `write` permission for `models` the button will not be displayed.

Has anyone done anything like this? Is there more "elegant" solution than this?

thanks!

**P.S.** Of course user permission will also be checked on the server side too.

Comment: I've done something like this before. I had an admin page that was restricted based on the user. What you're doing is basically what I did. I used php as my backend and validated it through checking the PHP session (not the best but worked with what I had/knew). And it successfully hid the page. If your solution is working, then I wouldn't fuss too much about it, though you might want an `else` statement in the render just to return something like `you do not have access to this page` or something, just so users can see something, rather than think the page is broken

Comment: Thank you, but `else` statement in this case is not required, because I want to hide some action controls like 'edit' or 'delete' buttons in already opened page.

Comment: that's fine, if you do something like `{ exists && <div> some stuff </div> }` and exists is falsey, then the div won't exist (not just `display: none`)

Comment: Hey... did you find any online source for this solution?

Comment: hi, no i didn't

Comment: I think you have to return something in the else though, otherwise i believe react will throw an error when the user is not authorized. Even a return '' should be sufficient.

Comment: @AntonNovik What is your situation with this?

Comment: For correct code, you'll need a different render function:
`render() {
return (this.allowed()? this.props.children : null);}`

Answer (score 14):

Well I think I understood what you want. I have done something that works for me and I like the way I have it but I understand that other viable solutions are out there.

What I wrote was an HOC react-router style.

Basically I have my **PermissionsProvider** where I init the users permissions. I have another **withPermissions** HOC that injects the permissions I provided earlier into my component.

So if I ever need to check permissions in that specific component I can access them easily.

```
// PermissionsProvider.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import hoistStatics from "hoist-non-react-statics";

class PermissionsProvider extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    permissions: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  static contextTypes = {
    permissions: PropTypes.array,
  };

  static childContextTypes = {
    permissions: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  getChildContext() {
    // maybe you want to transform the permissions somehow
    // maybe run them through some helpers. situational stuff
    // otherwise just return the object with the props.permissions
    // const permissions = doSomething(this.props.permissions);
    // maybe add some validation methods
    return { permissions: this.props.permissions };
  }

  render() {
    return React.Children.only(this.props.children);
  }
}

const withPermissions = Component => {
  const C = (props, context) => {
    const { wrappedComponentRef, ...remainingProps } = props;

    return (
      <Component permissions={context.permissions} {...remainingProps} ref={wrappedComponentRef} />
    );
  };

  C.displayName = `withPermissions(${Component.displayName || Component.name})`;
  C.WrappedComponent = Component;
  C.propTypes = {
    wrappedComponentRef: PropTypes.func
  };

  C.contextTypes = {
    permissions: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  return hoistStatics(C, Component);
};

export { PermissionsProvider as default, withPermissions };
```

Ok I know this is a lot of code. But these are HOC (you can learn more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)).

> A higher-order component (HOC) is an advanced technique in React for
>   reusing component logic. HOCs are not part of the React API, per se.
>   They are a pattern that emerges from React’s compositional nature.
>   Concretely, a higher-order component is a function that takes a
>   component and returns a new component.

Basically I did this because I was inspired by what react-router did.
Whenever you want to know some routing stuff you can just add the decorator **@withRouter** and they inject props into your component. **So why not do the same thing?**

1. First you must setup the permissions with the provider
2. Then you use the **withPermissions** decorator on the components that check permissions

---

```
//App render
return (
   <PermissionsProvider permissions={permissions}>
      <SomeStuff />
   </PermissionsProvider>
);
```

Somewhere inside **SomeStuff** you have a widely spread Toolbar that checks permissions?

```
@withPermissions
export default class Toolbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { permissions } = this.props;

    return permissions.canDoStuff ? <RenderStuff /> : <HeCantDoStuff />; 
  }
}
```

If you can't use decorators you export the Toolbar like this

```
export default withPermissions(Toolbar);
```

Here is a codesandbox where I showed it in practice:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lxor8v3pkz

NOTES:

- I really really simplified the permissions because that logic comes from your end and for demo purposes I simplified them.
- I assumed the permissions were an array so that is why I check the PropTypes.array in the HOCs
- It's a really long and complicated answer and I tried to articulate at my best ability. Please don't grill me for some mistakes here and there :)

Comment: @AntonNovik What is your situation with this?

Answer (score 7):

The approach that suggested by @lokuzt is great.

And you can go even further in order to simplify your code.

First of all, every protected component has some **requirement** to be satisfied for render. You need to define a function that takes **requirement** to render and **credentials** of the current user as parameters. It must return **true** or **false**.

```
function isSatisfied(requirement, credentials) {
  if (...) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Further, we have to define a [HOC (Higher-Order Component)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) using the [new context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) from ReactJS.

```
const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext();

function protect(requirement, WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Consumer>
          { credentials => isSatisfied(requirement, credentials)
            ? <WrappedComponent {...this.props}>
                {this.props.children}
              </WrappedComponent>
            : null
          }
        </Consumer>
      );
    }
  }; 
}
```

Now you can decorate your components:

```
const requireAdmin = {...}; // <- this is your requirement

class AdminPanel extends Component {
  ...
}

export default protect(requireAdmin, AdminPanel);
```

or even third-party components:

```
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

const AdminButton = protect(requireAdmin, Button);
```

Credentials have to be passed by ReactJS context API:

```
class MyApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const {credentials} = this.props;

    <Provider value={credentials}>
      ...

         <AdminPanel/>

         <AdminButton>
           Drop Database
         </AdminButton>
      ...
    </Provider>
  }
}
```

Here is my extended [implementation](https://github.com/nurzhan-saktaganov/react-rbac-guard/) on github.

The [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/znmxlw59jm) is also available too.